# Access gem source code in Cloud 9

Tags: cloud9-ide

I would like to open up and edit gem source code but I can't figure out how to in cloud 9.

Stack Overflow wants me to make this question longer but it really is that simple. Where is the damn code at?

Comment: Are you still having this issue? If not please choose an answer to accept, or submit your own. Also upvote any that have been helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the location of gems by issuing one of the following commands:

- `rvm gemdir`
- `gem environment` (look for the gem path)

Answer (score 1):

Cloud9 operates like any other terminal. The following is helpful if the gem has a unique name, as you will get fewer (better) results. I will use `will_paginate` for example:

```
sudo locate will_paginate
```

Since Cloud9 comes packaged with light permissions for the main user, you will benefit most from using `sudo` like above.

On my machine, the results include sub-directories in the two following locations:

```
/home/hstevens/.gem/ruby/gems/will_paginate-3.0.7
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/will_paginate-3.0.7
```

Depending on whether you installed your gem as root or not, your results should include one or both of the above locations. (Actual paths may vary slightly.)

Comment: sudo locate gem_name doesn't do anything. I use will_paginate so I even tried that exact example. I've searched/opened files with the terminal before but it's very tedious(and won't let me open it outside the terminal). I'm asking how can I manually look through the folders the same way you browse through your application files. If anything, I would like to browse and learn about the external code I'm using and this is just too painful to do in the terminal.

Comment: Oh you are talking about the IDE's file browser? I suggest you put that in your question. And `locate` may not be installed on your VM then. I am used to it so much at work (CentOS 7) that I forget it is not installed by default everywhere.